# A tricky elementary number theory question - least common multiple

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$M=m_1+m_2+...+m_n$. Show that $lcm\{m_1,m_2,...,m_n\}=M$ iff $m_i=M$ for some $i$ and $m_j=0$ for $j \neq i$.

My attempt:
I can only prove this when $n=2$. My strategy is to solve $M=i \cdot m_1$, $M=j 
\cdot m_2$, $m_1+m_2=M$. This requires $i=\frac{j}{j-1} \notin \mathbb{N}$. But I can't prove the general case. Is there a established result here?

Comment: Are you asking to prove $\text{lcm}(M,0,0,0,\ldots,0)=M$?

Comment: Does, say $\text{lcm}(0,3,0)$ actually have a sensible meaning?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Iff means if and only if.

Comment: @Joffan $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, and then for two ideals $I,J$ the $gcd, lcm$ are just the generators of $I  + J$ respectively $I J$. So yes, it has. And you are right, this definition gives $lcm(m,0)=0$.

Comment: @Joffan I'd say $\text{lcm}(0,3,0)=0$. Would you agree?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it seems like the best option. Then I guess $\gcd(0,3,0)=3$ under that logic.

Comment: Technically, $\mathrm{lcm}(0,M)=0$, not $M$. $M$ is not a multiple of $0$.

Comment: $2+3+3+4=12$ is another counter-example. This is related to the question of what conjugacy classes of elements of $\Sigma_M$ are of order $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$6=1+2+3$$
is a counterexample.

Note that your problem is equivalent to $\sum \frac{m_i}{M}=1$, which reminded me of the well known relation
$$1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}$$

Joffan showed below how to iterate this.

**Another counterexample**

Here is another way to construct a counterexample: Pick $n$ to be a perfect number.

Then 
$$n=\sum_{d|n, d<n} d$$
and the lcm of the elements on the right hand side is $n$.

The first perfect number is $6$ which leads to the same example as above, so let us look at the next one:

$$28=1+2+4+7+14$$

Answer (score 1):

Building on the nice counterexample result from N.S., I'll just capture the iteration I noticed quickly:

$$\begin{align}
1=\frac 12 + \frac 13 + \color{blue}{\frac 16} & \quad \to \quad 6= 3+2+1 \\ 
1=\frac 12 + \frac 13 + \color{blue}{\frac1{12} +\frac 1{18} +\frac 1{36}} 
   & \quad \to \quad 36 = 18+12+3+2+1
\end{align}$$

Then I went looking for other results on unit fractions and found this [paper by Nishiyama, *Unit Fractions that sum to 1*](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2013-85-1/7/7.pdf), and used some of the techniques suggested there to find a set that didn't include $1$:

$$1=\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 17 +\frac 1{12} +\frac 1{42} 
   \quad \to \quad 84 = 42+21+12+7+2$$